# how to run a GET or POST method sequentially in node.js

Tags: node.js

> here is the code of index.js file

```
var request = require('request');
var requestHandling = require('../routes/request_handling_functions');

router.get("/example1", function (req, res) {

var result = 
requestHandling.requestMethodGet('http://localhost:8083/getUserInfo/865c2c25- 
d9e7-412d-a064-326bd66c9e9c', res);
console.log("===RESULT=====");
console.log(result);
});
```

in above code I want that function **requestMethodGet** return the result into result variable then I manipulate the result according to my need then show to user and also I am console my return result.
but here is the problem with it because Node.js is asynchronous language so first it print the result then it call the function **requestMethodGet**  that is so irritating.

> Here is the code of requestMethodGet

```
requestMethodGet: function (url, res) {

    //SET ALL THESE PARATMETER TO MAKE REQUEST
    request.get({url: url}, function (e, r, body) {

        var errorResult = module.exports.validateResponseeData(e);

        console.log("====errorResult===in===Get==method====");
        console.log(errorResult);
        if (errorResult != "continue") {
            console.log("===im in not continue");

            return errorResult;
        } else {

            //LOGING THE RESPONSE BODY
            log.info('body:', body);

            var responseData = JSON.parse(body);


console.log("======RESPONSE=========DATA=====================");
            console.log('error:', e);
            console.log('statusCode:', r && r.statusCode);
            console.log('body:', body);
            console.log("====================================");
            console.log(responseData);

            return responseData;
        }
    });
}
```

> I want that the router get method run the code in the sequence as the code write. but I search it everywhere I not found the any solution so come here to find my solution.
>   **if any information is needed to solve this question then please inform me.**

Comment: Just use `async/await` syntax or promises.

Comment: but where i apply async/await can u please give an example using my code. thank you

Comment: router.get("/example1", async function (req, res) {

    var result = await requestHandling.requestMethodGet('http://localhost:8083/getUserInfo/865c2c25-d9e7-412d-a064-326bd66c9e9c', res);
    console.log("===RESULT=====");
    console.log(result);

Comment: i use it like this but still it give the result undefined in the console

Comment: perhaps share the contents of the `requestMethodGet` function with us as well

Comment: Your `requestMethodGet` has to return a promise if you want it to be awaited. The example here seems to be good: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: @TommyBs i update my question please see it and thanks for reply

Comment: You don't seem to have posted the requestMethodGet function itself. What does the code for that function look like?

Comment: @TommyBs please check my question now i update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. It returns a promise from your requestMethodGet function and you then wait until that is resolved before logging the response. I suggest you read more on Promises to understand how this works.

```
 requestMethodGet: function (url, res) {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        //SET ALL THESE PARATMETER TO MAKE REQUEST
        request.get({url: url}, function (e, r, body) {

            var errorResult = module.exports.validateResponseeData(e);

            console.log("====errorResult===in===Get==method====");
            console.log(errorResult);
            if (errorResult != "continue") {
                console.log("===im in not continue");

                reject(errorResult);
            } else {

                //LOGING THE RESPONSE BODY
                log.info('body:', body);

                var responseData = JSON.parse(body);


    console.log("======RESPONSE=========DATA=====================");
                console.log('error:', e);
                console.log('statusCode:', r && r.statusCode);
                console.log('body:', body);
                console.log("====================================");
                console.log(responseData);

                resolve(responseData);
            }
        });

});
    }


//INDEX.js
router.get("/example1", function (req, res) {


requestHandling.requestMethodGet('http://localhost:8083/getUserInfo/865c2c25- 
d9e7-412d-a064-326bd66c9e9c', res).then((result) => {
      console.log("===RESULT=====");
console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("===Error=====");
console.log(err);
});

});
```

Comment: thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Promise` or `async/await`

Comment: i about these but i don't know how to use them in my code, please can give example with my code

Comment: Unless you provide some more details, this can hardly be considered an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).